# How to configure an Image as a button in motif

Tags: linux, user-interface, xlib, motif

I was wondering if it was possible to configure an Image as a pushbutton using the openmotif widget tool kit.

Basically the Image would act like a button and have activate callbacks similar to what happens with plain pushbuttons. How would this be possible in motif?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have the motif library compiled with support for `.jpeg`, `.png` and `.gif` images.... you have to read the **XmPushButton** or **XmPushButtonGadget** (or better, as they are subclasses of, by reading  **XmLabel** or **XmLabelGadget**) manual pages.  The image is selected by putting a `@` in front of the text resource string.  You can do this in the resources file for the application or in the `${HOME}/.Xdefaults` file.